# Creating a circle with a shaded area in MAUI

Tags: maui

I need to achieve something like this:

[image]

However, I am getting this instead:

[image]

I am not clear how the `FillArc` method works, with respect to start and end angles and about the last parameter called `clockwise`.

This is the class that implements `IDrawable` and it's responsible to draw the chart:

```
public class ElapsedTimeDrawable : IDrawable
{
    public DateTime StartTime { private get; set; }
    public DateTime EndTime { private get; set; }

    public void Draw(ICanvas canvas, RectF dirtyRect)
    {
        canvas.StrokeColor = Color.FromRgba("6599ff");
        canvas.StrokeSize = 5;
        canvas.DrawArc(15, 15, dirtyRect.Width - 30, dirtyRect.Height - 30, 0, 360, false, false);

        canvas.StrokeColor = Colors.Silver;
        canvas.StrokeSize = 1;
        canvas.DrawLine(dirtyRect.Width / 2, 10, dirtyRect.Width / 2, dirtyRect.Height - 10);
        canvas.DrawLine(10, dirtyRect.Height / 2, dirtyRect.Width - 10, dirtyRect.Height / 2);

        canvas.DrawString("0 h", dirtyRect.Width / 2, 0, HorizontalAlignment.Center);
        canvas.DrawString("6 h", dirtyRect.Width, dirtyRect.Height / 2, HorizontalAlignment.Center);
        canvas.DrawString("12 h", dirtyRect.Width / 2, dirtyRect.Height, HorizontalAlignment.Center);
        canvas.DrawString("18 h", 0, dirtyRect.Height / 2, HorizontalAlignment.Center);

        canvas.StrokeColor = Colors.Green;
        canvas.DrawPath(GetPathForTime(StartTime, dirtyRect));

        canvas.StrokeColor = Colors.Red;
        canvas.DrawPath(GetPathForTime(EndTime, dirtyRect));

        canvas.FillColor = Colors.LightGreen;
        canvas.FillPath(GetPathForShift(dirtyRect), WindingMode.EvenOdd);
    }

    private static PointF GetPoint(double hours, RectF dirtyRect)
    {
        double radio = (dirtyRect.Width - 30) / 2;

        // Tira la línea a la hora de inicio
        double theta;
        double y;
        double x;
        if (hours >= 0 && hours <= 6)   // cuadrante superior derecha
        {
            theta = hours * 360 / 24;
            y = dirtyRect.Height - radio * Math.Sin(theta * Math.PI / 180); // El positivo del Y va hacia abajo
            x = dirtyRect.Width / 2 + Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(radio, 2) - Math.Pow(y - dirtyRect.Height / 2, 2));
        }
        else if (hours > 6 && hours <= 12)  // cuadrante inferior derecha
        {
            theta = hours * 360 / 24 - 90;
            y = dirtyRect.Height / 2 + radio * Math.Sin(theta * Math.PI / 180); // El positivo del Y va hacia abajo
            x = dirtyRect.Width / 2 + Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(radio, 2) - Math.Pow(y - dirtyRect.Height / 2, 2));
        }
        else if (hours > 12 && hours <= 18)  // cuadrante inferior izquierda
        {
            theta = 360 - hours * 360 / 24 - 90;
            y = dirtyRect.Height / 2 + radio * Math.Sin(theta * Math.PI / 180); // El positivo del Y va hacia abajo
            x = dirtyRect.Width / 2 - Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(radio, 2) - Math.Pow(y - dirtyRect.Height / 2, 2));
        }
        else // cuadrante superior izquierda
        {
            theta = 90 - (360 - hours * 360 / 24);
            y = dirtyRect.Height / 2 - radio * Math.Sin(theta * Math.PI / 180); // El positivo del Y va hacia abajo
            x = dirtyRect.Width / 2 - Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(radio, 2) - Math.Pow(y - dirtyRect.Height / 2, 2));
        }

        return new PointF((float)x, (float)y);
    }

    private static PathF GetPathForTime(DateTime time, RectF dirtyRect)
    {
        PathF path = new();
        path.MoveTo(dirtyRect.Center.X, dirtyRect.Center.Y);

        path.LineTo(GetPoint(time.TimeOfDay.TotalHours, dirtyRect));

        return path;
    }

    private PathF GetPathForShift(RectF dirtyRect)
    {
        PathF path = new();

        double ahora = EndTime.TimeOfDay.TotalHours;
        PointF firstPoint = GetPoint(StartTime.TimeOfDay.TotalHours, dirtyRect);

        path.MoveTo(dirtyRect.Center.X, dirtyRect.Center.Y);
        path.LineTo(firstPoint);

        float startAngle = Math.Abs(90 - (float)(StartTime.TimeOfDay.TotalHours * 360 / 24));
        float endAngle = Math.Abs(90 - (float)(ahora * 360 / 24));
        path.AddArc(15, 15, dirtyRect.Width - 30, dirtyRect.Height - 30, startAngle, endAngle, true);
        path.LineTo(dirtyRect.Center.X, dirtyRect.Center.Y);

        return path;
    }
```

The most curious thing is the area that is painted near to the right edge of the circle.

I am sure I am close to the goal, but I need some help.

The shape rectangle have width 200 and height 200.

(
I created a custom control for this, with this XAML file

```
<ContentView
    x:Class="TimeApp.Controls.ShiftControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui/design"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TimeApp.Controls"
    xmlns:drawables="clr-namespace:TimeApp.Controls"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <ContentView.Resources>
        <drawables:ElapsedTimeDrawable x:Key="shift" />
    </ContentView.Resources>
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <GraphicsView x:Name="ProgressView"
                    Drawable="{StaticResource shift}"
                    BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Primary}"
                    HeightRequest="200"
                    WidthRequest="200"/>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentView>
```

)

Comment: The arc is the curved line on the green path. It runs between ~ 8 and 3 o'clock. Which probably isn't what you expected. Its bounds do not match the circle you have. Start with a three-hour arc, and get that correct, by adjusting parameters to see what happens. Do different 3 hour periods, (0-3, 1-4, etc) until you understand how the angles and direction work. Then try longer periods.